# SQLSTATE[HY000] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I tried to get Laravel working on a remote server. But when I ran the "php artisan migrate" command it responds with:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]  [2002] Connection refused
```

I Google'd for solutions and so far I tried:

- Disable .env by renaming it to .env.off;
- Setting up the database credentials directly into database.php;
- Adding port 3306;
- The DB user has all privileges;
- Tried running it as 'localhost', 127.0.0.1 and remote IP;
- Running a plain PHP PDO connection, it connects;
- When I used the remote IP it says "Acces Denied for user 'daniel..."

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:[secret]=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=daniel
DB_USERNAME=daniel
DB_PASSWORD=4K^2N(h}%V&S

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'daniel'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'daniel'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '4K^2N(h}%V&S'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: so when you use the mysql command line tool and the privileges given in your .env file it works and you can do queries?

Comment: @herrjeh42 Yes, how strange...

Comment: My only thought is whether your config settings are cached at all. Try running `php artisan config:clear` to clear any cached settings out and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I admit: sometimes I remove all caches manually (without artisan), and sometimes this solves my problem.